# `[innerHTML]` - html tags are missing

Tags: angular, angular5

In my variable  I declared like :

```
title:any="<h2>Arif</h2>";
```

In my template I tried both way :

```
<content [innerHTML]="title"></content>
<div [innerHTML]="title"></div>
```

Both of them has no `h2` tag at all. what is the problem? also how to just replace the `content` tag using `h2` element?

any one help me?

Comment: Have you tried `<content>{{title}}</content>`?

Comment: Try making title a "string" type than an "any" type.

Comment: Tried both way adding `{{` and setting as `string` - not helps

Comment: Problem might be somewhere else , see working example here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hdbjzu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: @PardeepJain how can i replace the element instead of adding the html, since i am getting the tags from backend

Answer (score 0):

I changed the condition from :

```
<div class="popup-overlay" *ngIf="showPopup"></div>
<div class="popupDesc" *ngIf="showPopup">
```

to

```
<div class="popup-overlay" [hidden] = "!showPopup"></div>
<div class="popupDesc" [hidden] = "!showPopup" >
```

Now the `innerHTML` works fine.